# Is the free energy density analytic in temperature at the Kosterlitz-Thouless phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, analyticity

I know that the KT transition is infinite-order so the free energy density is a smooth (i.e. infinitely differentiable) function of temperature, but is the function actually analytic at the critical temperature $T_{KT}$?  Slide 3 of [these slides](http://www.dcps.sav.sk/seminars/brat_12.pdf) says that it is, but page 8 of [these notes](http://www.mit.edu/~levitov/8.334/notes/XYnotes1.pdf) says that it has a smooth essential singularity proportional to $\exp(-c\, /\sqrt{T - T_{KT}})$, where $c$ is a constant.  Which source is correct?

Comment: It's wrong to say that the function and it's derivatives are "analytic". That sentence actually betrays the mistake. What is meant is that the fucntion and all its derivates are continuous, it obviously does not make sense to say that a function and all its derivates are analytic, because then you could just as well say that the function is analytic, no need to mention the derivatives in that case. Then you know that the free energy will have a "singular part" proportional to $1/\xi^2$,  so, there should be no doubt about the non-analytic behavior here.

Comment: @CountIblis So just to be completely clear, you are saying that the slides are wrong and the notes are right: the free energy density is smooth but nonanalytic at $T_{KT}$. Right?

Comment: Yes, only the word "analytic" should not have been used in that sentence,  it should be clear that what is meant is that the function and all it's derivate are smooth functions.

Comment: @CountIblis The word "analytic" should not have been used in *which* sentence?

Comment: "Free energy and all its derivatives are analytic functions of the temperature"